# Trying to compile X Window System and getting errors that I don't know

Tags: x11, compiling, ld

I have double-checked that I have every dependency to build X and that they are all at the latest version.
I'm not even sure where to begin with these errors, so I was hoping someone here could help me.
Compiling on WSL2 if it matters.

Compiling using the build.sh method.

Here's the command I'm using:
`./util/modular/build.sh --clone $HOME/Xbuild`

Here's the error:

```
/home/mason/lx-os/cross-tools/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/ld: warning: libXau.so.6, needed by /home/mason/Xbuild/lib/libxcb.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/home/mason/lx-os/cross-tools/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/ld: warning: libXdmcp.so.6, needed by /home/mason/Xbuild/lib/libxcb.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/home/mason/lx-os/cross-tools/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/ld: warning: libxcb-shm.so.0, needed by ../image/.libs/libxcb-image.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/home/mason/lx-os/cross-tools/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /home/mason/Xbuild/lib/libxcb.so: undefined reference to `XauGetBestAuthByAddr'
/home/mason/lx-os/cross-tools/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/ld: ../image/.libs/libxcb-image.so: undefined reference to `xcb_shm_put_image'
/home/mason/lx-os/cross-tools/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /home/mason/Xbuild/lib/libxcb.so: undefined reference to `XauDisposeAuth'
/home/mason/lx-os/cross-tools/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/ld: ../image/.libs/libxcb-image.so: undefined reference to `xcb_shm_get_image'
/home/mason/lx-os/cross-tools/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /home/mason/Xbuild/lib/libxcb.so: undefined reference to `XdmcpWrap'
/home/mason/lx-os/cross-tools/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/ld: ../image/.libs/libxcb-image.so: undefined reference to `xcb_shm_get_image_reply'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [Makefile:648: test_xcb_image] Error 1
```

I thought that running `sudo ldconfig` would fix it, but it did not.

Comment: Where are `libXau.so.6`, `libXdmcp.so.6` and `libxcb-shm.so.0` located?

Comment: Why don't you install [Debian](https://debian.org/) on your computer? See also https://linuxfromscratch.org/ ... you could need to set your `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` so read [*Advanced Linux Programming*](https://mentorembedded.github.io/advancedlinuxprogramming/) and [Linux Program Library Howto](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/) and the documentation of [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) and [binutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/binutils/). See [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html)

Comment: ... and [environ(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/environ.7.html), and [ld(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ld.1.html), [gcc(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gcc.1.html)

Comment: rfmodulator, they are in the include folder.

Comment: I'm running on WSL2 ubuntu, which I hope is close enough?

Comment: @MasonM Include folder? They *should* be in a library folder, presumably `/home/mason/Xbuild/lib/` or `../image/.libs/` ...or somewhere that `ldconfig` can find them.

Comment: @rfmodulator I solved it by running the script as root, not sure why but it did it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running the build script as root solved it.